How to make an insert happen even if there is an exception?
I want the insert to occur even if there is an exception, how do I do this in postgresql?
In my case, I want the error to pop, but the insert also occurs
DO
$$
DECLARE
    VRecord        RECORD;
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM table_1;

    FOR VRecord IN 
        SELECT 
            GENERATE_SERIES(1, 10) id
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'VRecord.id [%]', VRecord.id;

        INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES (VRecord.id);

        IF (VRecord.id > 5) THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'erro em VRecord.id [%]', VRecord.id;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END
$$

I tried to do this:
but I only get notice, I wanted the error to be popped and the insertion to occur
DO $$
DECLARE
    VRecord        RECORD;
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM table_1;

    FOR VRecord IN 
        SELECT 
            GENERATE_SERIES(1, 10) id
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            RAISE NOTICE 'VRecord.id [%]', VRecord.id;

            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES (VRecord.id);
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN others THEN
                    RAISE NOTICE 'Erro na inserção para VRecord.id [%]: %', VRecord.id, SQLERRM;
            END;

            IF (VRecord.id > 5) THEN
                RAISE EXCEPTION 'Erro em VRecord.id [%]', VRecord.id;
            END IF;

        EXCEPTION
            WHEN others THEN
                RAISE NOTICE 'Erro capturado em VRecord.id [%]: %', VRecord.id, SQLERRM;
        END;
    END LOOP;
END
$$;

Just to reinforce, the error is not in the insert, the error is when VRecord.id is greater than 5, I forced this exception for this specific case.

Not possible, Autonomous Transactions are not supported by PostgreSQL. There is a workaround using dblink: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/migrating-oracle-autonomous-transactions-to-postgresql/

Can I do something using savepoint? I saw about savepoint in the documentation but I was a little confused @FrankHeikens

Yes you can but it depends on the logic you need. You can also organize all blocks and their exception handler in such a way that the function will never fail. Even when one or more steps the functions does, did fail. It's just not as straightforward and you still might have missed some case.

This makes no sense. Something went wrong with the INSERT, which is what causes the exception. If you try to make it do it anyway, you're going to get the exception again, because you didn't fix the problem. Instead of trying to come up with some ridiculous scheme to bypass the exception, it's a much better idea to fix the problem that's causing the exception in the first place.

What you are asking for is unreasonable.
You are getting the error because something went wrong with the INSERT: you were out of disk space, the was a constraint violation, an administrator killed your session or something else. If the INSERT failed once, and the reason for that failure persists, you cannot make it succeed.
Imagine that you are walking into a shop to buy something, and the salesman tells you that they don't have what you want. Do you think you can just stomp your foot and wail, and suddenly the stocks get magically replenished?
